# What is the name of Symfony function for "fancy array_merge()"?

Tags: php, symfony

I remember I read about it somewhere in the docs and saw it being used in the code, but **can't remember its name**. It was described as "fancy way of doing array_merge()" or something. It allowed to merge two arrays with parameters and included some simple type checking.

```php
function doSomething ($params) {
    $defaultParams = [
        'foo' => false,
        'bar' => 1,
    ];
    $p = whatsTheFunctionName($params, $defaultParams, [/* foo is bool, bar is int */]);
}
```

Comment: Could be the `OptionsResolver` component: `"improved replacement for the array_replace PHP function"` https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html

Comment: @Marleen, yes, it's `OptionsResolver` for sure! Thanks! If you'll write your comment as the answer, I gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the OptionsResolver component: "improved replacement for the array_replace PHP function".

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html